# Counters to distinguish Insert Hotspot / Page Split by seeing PAGELATCH_EX

Tags: sql-server, performance, waits, performance-tuning

`Insert hotspot` and excessive `page splits` are common reasons for `PAGELATCH_EX`.

What are the other counters that can be used to confirm whether the wait is from insert hotspot or page split?

Note: I am using SQL Server 2012.

**REFERENCES**

1. [sys.dm_os_wait_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx)

Comment: Have you considered using the Page Split/Sec counter and correlating that with your pagelatch_ex wait type?

Comment: What resource are the page latch waits on? Index with sequential insert pattern? Index with random insert pattern? None of the above?

Comment: @MartinSmith The dmv `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` gives me only count and wait time. Can you please explain how to determine on which resources the `PAGELATCH_EX` is waiting?